# Rspec: Mock recaptcha verification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to create a request spec for a form submission and my recaptcha verification is causing the test to fail.  I have a pretty simple test:

```
RSpec.describe "PotentialClients", type: :request do
  let(:pc_attributes) { ... }

  describe "POST /potential_clients" do

    it "should create record" do
      expect { post potential_clients_path, params: { potential_client: pc_attributes } }
        .to change(PotentialClient, :count).by(+1)
    end

  end
end
```

I run into an issue because in `PotentialClients#create` I make a call to `verify_recaptcha?` which returns `false` in the test instead of `true`:

```
# potential_clients_controller.rb
def create
    @potential_client = PotentialClient.new(potential_client_params)
    page_success = verify_recaptcha?(params[:recaptcha_token], 'lead_creation_page')

    if page_success && @potential_client.save
        ...
    end
end

# application_controller.rb
def verify_recaptcha?(token, recaptcha_action)
  secret_key = ENV['CAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY']

  uri = URI.parse("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=#{secret_key}&response=#{token}")
  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
  json = JSON.parse(response.body)
  if json['success'] && json['score'] > RECAPTCHA_MINIMUM_SCORE && (json['action'] == "lead_creation_page" || json['action'] == "lead_creation_modal")
    return true
  elsif json['success'] == false && json["error-codes"].include?("timeout-or-duplicate")
    return true
  end

  return false
end
```

**How should I mock the call to `verify_recapthca?` so that my test passes?**  I've tried:

```
allow(PotentialClient).to receive(:verify_recaptcha?).and_return(true)
# and 
allow_any_instance_of(PotentialClient).to receive(:verify_recaptcha?).and_return(true)
```

but both threw errors:

```
PotentialClient(...) does not implement: verify_recaptcha?
```

Comment: I see you edited my answer. I don't mind edits, and I'm glad you were able to solve your problem, but in this case since the changes to the code were substantial it probably would have been better to post your own answer and accept it. As it is, the changed code in my answer no longer matches the sentence preceding it and further edits would be necessary for it to make sense.

Comment: My apologies!  I'm new to edits.  Would you like to change it back and I can submit a new response?

Comment: That might be best, but it’s up to you. It’s not a big deal to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
allow(PotentialClient).to receive(:verify_recaptcha?).and_return(true)
```

This isn't working because—as the error message says—PotentialClient (the model) doesn't have a method called `verify_recaptcha?`. The method is defined in ApplicationController, which is extended by PotentialClientsController, and that's where you need to mock it.

My Rails is rusty, but it looks like in an rspec-rails controller spec the current instance of the controller is exposed by the `controller` method. In that case, what you want is this:

```
allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:verify_recaptcha?).and_return(true)
```